Is there a way to assign my values from the file to a specific date also from the file but from column 1
This is my ViewModel in my program:
using LiveChartsCore; 
using LiveChartsCore.SkiaSharpView; 
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel; 
using LiveChartsCore.Measure; 
using LiveChartsCore.SkiaSharpView.Painting; 
using SkiaSharp; 
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.IO; 
using HeatingGridAvaloniaApp.Models;

namespace HeatingGridAvaloniApp.ViewModels
{
    public class VisualizerViewModel
    {
        ResultDataManager resultDataManager = new ResultDataManager();

        // Returns the maximum heat data for a given unit
        public static double GetValues(string unitName)
        {
            // File path containing the data
            string filePath = "Assets/heatingGrids.csv";
            // Read the CSV file and split the values
            string[] values = File.ReadAllText(filePath).Split(',');
    
            // Switch statement to extract the maximum heat data based on the unit name
            switch (unitName)
            {
                case "GB":
                    return double.Parse(values[4]); // Extract maximum heat for GB

                case "OB":
                    return double.Parse(values[10]); // Extract maximum heat for OB

                case "GM":
                    return double.Parse(values[16]); // Extract maximum heat for GM

                case "EK":
                    return double.Parse(values[22]); // Extract maximum heat for EK

                default:
                    throw new ArgumentException($"Unit name {unitName} not found in the file.");
            }
        }
    
        // Reads data for the graph
        static List<double> ReadProducedHeat(string filename, string unitname)
        {
            List<double> producedHeat = new List<double>();
    
            // Read the CSV file containing the produced heat data
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(filename))
            {
                reader.ReadLine(); // Skip header line
    
                // Read each line of the CSV file
                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    var line = reader.ReadLine();

                    if (line != null)
                    {
                        var values = line.Split(',');
    
                        // Check if the unit name matches
                        if (values[2] == unitname)
                        {
                            producedHeat.Add(double.Parse(values[3])); // Add the produced heat value
                        }
                        // Check if the unit name is combined with another unit (e.g., "GB+OB")
                        else if (values[2] == $"{unitname}+GB" || values[2] == $"{unitname}+OB" || values[2] == $"{unitname}+EK" || values[2] == $"{unitname}+GM")
                        {
                            if (!(double.Parse(values[3]) <= GetValues(unitname)))
                            {
                                producedHeat.Add(GetValues(unitname)); // Add the maximum heat value for the unit
                            } 
                            else 
                            {   
                                producedHeat.Add(double.Parse(values[3]));
                            }
                        }
                        // Check if the unit name is combined with another unit (e.g., "GB+EK")
                        else if (values[2] == $"GB+{unitname}")
                        {
                            double value = double.Parse(values[3]);
                            if (!(value < GetValues("GB")))
                            {
                                producedHeat.Add(value - GetValues("GB")); // Subtract the maximum heat value for the unit
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                continue;
                            }
                        }
                        else if (values[2] == $"OB+{unitname}")
                        {
                            double value = double.Parse(values[3]);
                            if (!(value < GetValues("OB")))
                            {
                                producedHeat.Add(value - GetValues("OB")); // Subtract the maximum heat value for the unit 
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                continue;
                            }
                        }
                        else if (values[2] == $"EK+{unitname}")
                        {
                            double value = double.Parse(values[3]);
                            if (!(value < GetValues("EK")))
                            {
                                producedHeat.Add(value - GetValues("EK")); // Subtract the maximum heat value for the unit
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                continue;
                            }
                        }
                        else if (values[2] == $"GM+{unitname}")
                        {
                            double value = double.Parse(values[3]);
                            if (!(value < GetValues("GM")))
                            {
                                producedHeat.Add(value - GetValues("EK")); // Subtract the maximum heat value for the unit
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                continue;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    
            return producedHeat; // Return the list of produced heat values
        }
    
        // Graph logic
        public ISeries[] Series { get; set; } =
        {
            // Initialize the series with the produced heat data for each unit
            new StackedAreaSeries<double>
            {
                Values = ReadProducedHeat("Assets/ResultData.csv", "GB"), // Produced heat data for GB
                Fill = new SolidColorPaint(SKColors.Blue) // Set color for GB
            },
            new StackedAreaSeries<double>
            {
                Values = ReadProducedHeat("Assets/ResultData.csv", "OB"), // Produced heat data for OB
                Fill = new SolidColorPaint(SKColors.Orange) // Set color for OB
            },
            new StackedAreaSeries<double>
            {
                Values = ReadProducedHeat("Assets/ResultData.csv", "GM"), // Produced heat data for GM
                Fill = new SolidColorPaint(SKColors.Red) // Set color for GM
            },
            new StackedAreaSeries<double>
            {
                Values = ReadProducedHeat("Assets/ResultData.csv", "EK"), // Produced heat data for EK
                Fill = new SolidColorPaint(SKColors.Green) // Set color for EK
            }
        };
    
        // X and Y axes properties
        public Axis[] XAxes { get; set; } // X-axis
        public Axis[] YAxes { get; set; } // Y-axis
    
        // Constructor
        public VisualizerViewModel()
        {
            // Initialize X and Y axes
            XAxes = new Axis[]
            {
                new Axis
                {
                    CrosshairLabelsBackground = SKColors.DarkOrange.AsLvcColor(),
                    CrosshairLabelsPaint = new SolidColorPaint(SKColors.DarkRed, 1),
                    CrosshairPaint = new SolidColorPaint(SKColors.DarkOrange, 1),
                    Labeler = value => value.ToString("N2") // Labeler function to format X-axis labels
                }
            };
    
            YAxes = new Axis[]
            {
                new Axis
                {
                    CrosshairLabelsBackground = SKColors.DarkOrange.AsLvcColor(),
                    CrosshairLabelsPaint = new SolidColorPaint(SKColors.DarkRed, 1),
                    CrosshairPaint = new SolidColorPaint(SKColors.DarkOrange, 1),
                    CrosshairSnapEnabled = true // Enable snapping for Y-axis
                }
            };
        }
    
        public decimal NetCostAverage
        {
            get => resultDataManager.AverageNetCost;
            set => resultDataManager.AverageNetCost = Math.Round(value, 2);
        }
    
        public decimal Co2Average
        {
            get => resultDataManager.AverageCo2;
            set => resultDataManager.AverageCo2 = Math.Round(value, 2);
        }
    }
}

In details I want each value that i read from the file to be assigned to the date that is also in the file. In the same row as the value that I read.
Can you help me? I can't figure it out.
I am using Avalonia and LiveCharts 2.0, in this case I am using a basic stacked area diagram from their site.
I tried to assign the dates to values in the stacked area series but it does not work. I keep on getting some errors and I think this diagram might not be able to do what I want.
My main problem is that on the charts the values are displayed from left to right without being ordered correctly.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
